# hyperlink in in checkboxfield detailsview

Tags: asp.net

In my detailsview control, i have several checkedboxfield with boolean = true. What I want have hyperlink on any text such as HeaderText of the datafield in order to navigate to other page. Is it possible? If not, any suggestion?

For mode details, When click the hyperlink in gridview, the detailsview will show the details which checkbox will checked if boolean=true and unchecked if false. I want to have hyperlink text on Checked CheckedBoxField (Unchecked Checkbox I hide it by code behind).

Below is the aspx:

`

```
    <Fields>
         <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Sample_Preparation_SP" HeaderImageUrl="~/Images/Coal/Coal.jpg"
                    HeaderText="Sample_Preparation" Text="Sample_Preparation" />


        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Free_Moisture_FM" HeaderImageUrl="~/Images/Biomass/Wood Chips.jpg"
            HeaderText="Free_Moisture_FM" SortExpression="Free_Moisture_FM" Text="Free Moisture" />


        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Inherent_Moisture_IM" HeaderImageUrl="~/Images/Coal/Coal.jpg"
            HeaderText="Inherent_Moisture_IM" SortExpression="Inherent Moisture" Text="Inherent Moisture" />


        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Total_Moisture_TM" HeaderText="Total_Moisture_TM" SortExpression="Total_Moisture_TM" HeaderImageUrl="~/Images/Biomass/Wood Pellet3.jpg" Text="Total Moisture" />


        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Gross_Calorific_Value_GCV" HeaderText="Gross_Calorific_Value_GCV"
            SortExpression="Gross_Calorific_Value_GCV" HeaderImageUrl="~/Images/Biomass/EFB.jpg" Text="Gross Calorific Value" />


        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Net_Calorific_Value_NCV" HeaderText="Net_Calorific_Value_NCV" SortExpression="Net_Calorific_Value_NCV" HeaderImageUrl="~/Images/Biomass/Wood Chips.jpg" Text="Net Calorific Value" />


    </Fields>


</asp:DetailsView>


<asp:SqlDataSource 
            ID="SqlDataSource1" 
            runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString2 %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT [SampleID],[Sample_Preparation_SP], [Free_Moisture_FM], [Inherent_Moisture_IM],  [Total_Moisture_TM]  ,[Gross_Calorific_Value_GCV], [Net_Calorific_Value_NCV] FROM [tbl_SampleRegistration] WHERE SampleID =@SampleID" >

    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="SampleID" QueryStringField="SampleID" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>`
```

Comment: What have your tried, can you post some example code?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Template Fields for Details View so you can customise things to any level.

See this excellent link from MSDN

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288033.aspx
```

Comment: Yes, I saw the articles which mention "The CheckBoxField renders as a disabled check box that is checked if the data field's value is True (or YES), and unchecked otherwise (False/NO)". But I want to hyperlink the text 'True / Yes' to navigate to other aspx page.  How?

Comment: If i am not wrong you can use links like <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Calorific")) == true ? "Yes" : "No" %>'  inside a template field